# How can I make my javafx app auto update itself?

Tags: java, javafx-9

I am currently creating a simple javafx application and want to make an "check for updates" button.

When this button gets pressed, it checks for any available updates. If it does find one, it prompts the user about that and asks permission to update itself.

How could this be implemented?

**Note:** I am using Java  9, not 8, if this is useful.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [update4j](https://github.com/update4j/update4j/)

From the author:

> The update4j framework is the first auto-update and launcher framework completely compatible with Java 9. Easily host your application files anywhere in the cloud accesible via a URL (even Google Drive, Dropbox, Amazon S3, or Maven Central) and you can synchronize them with all your distributed applications.
>
> Update4j has made security its priority. Signing your files is as easy as providing your private key to the framework on your dev machine, and it will do the job itself. On the client side, you should load the public key into the framework and it will automatically verify each and every downloaded file. It will forcefully reject any files without or with invalid signatures. This is an optional feature.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising